# OS Time in Python 3.8.5

Tags: python, django

I've got the following dictionary in my code:

```
{
"morning": now.hour > 0,
"afternoon": now.hour > 12,
"evening": now.hour > 18,
"bit_late": now.hour > 21,
}
```

It's part of a Django project (v3.1), and whenever I run the server it throws up no errors, but it is using UTC time instead of my local system's time (+ 5 1/2 UTC). Hence, when I viewed the page at 3 PM, it wished me "Good morning" (which it's programmed to do). I've included the `datetime` library, but I don't know how to use it or any other library to try and get the program to run using system time.

Am I missing any particular library? What method should I use to get the system time, and where do I put it?

```py
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

This is the code I used for `now`, just for reference!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You won't know the user's timezone, period. You can make an educated guess based on their IP and an IP-geolocation database, but that's it. You need to do this in the browser in Javascript, if anything.

Comment: This is unclear. Are you referring to a server in a different time zone? If this is the case, how do you run code on it, and how would you expect it to know where in the world you are when you run code on it?

Comment: For example, if my time zone is UTC +5 1/2, can the computer find out my system's time? Or is this happening because I'm running Linux Mint, where the system time is always UTC? I think it's the latter, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: *What* computer? Since you're talking about Django, you talk about a server separate from a visitor's computer with a browser? The server only knows what's in the HTTP request sent to the server, and a timezone isn't part of that information.

Comment: if this is just for showing some *greeting messages* then I recommend using js on the client-side.

Comment: @deceze I was talking about the user's computer. Then I realised that Django wasn't actually meant for this kind of thing and simply used JS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I've got my answer. I simply used JavaScript to display the message instead of trying something with Django. Thanks to everyone!